# Cannot suspend because cdrom_id and udevd are in uninterruptible sleep

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, udev, suspend, scsi

I upgraded the Linux kernel on my Gentoo Linux system from 4.9.76 to 5.4.38 about two weeks ago.  Since then, my dvd drive will stop spinning up when I insert a dvd and my laptop can no longer suspend to RAM.  This still works right after boot, but will start playing up after about a week (twice so far).

I find that the processes `cdrom_id` and `udev` are in an uninterruptible sleep state (indicated as `D` by `ps` - I added `dmesg` output to the bottom of this post).  Since the former is the child of the latter, I suspect `cdrom_id` is the culprit.  Also, switching from `systemd udev` to `eudev` didn't help.  [This bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=638887) from 2011 shows something similar, related to a kernel bug involving a `check_disk_change()` call.  A diff shows me that this call has been removed from `drivers/cdrom/cdrom.c` in the kernel source between the two kernel versions mentioned, but I am not sufficiently knowledgable to understand much more from that diff.

Is this a bug in the Linux kernel?  If so, should I report it - where/how?  Would compiling the scsi cdrom driver as a module (`sr_mod`) provide a workaround, in the sense that unloading and reloading the module would prevent me from having to reboot my laptop every week? (As a sport, I try to keep rebooting to a minimum; the last one before this was in November, and once a week costs me points ;-)).

"Appendix": dmesg output when trying to suspend to RAM:

```
Sat May 23 08:30:04 2020 PM: suspend entry (deep)
Sat May 23 08:30:04 2020 Filesystems sync: 0.002 seconds
Sat May 23 08:30:04 2020 Freezing user space processes ... 
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 Freezing of tasks failed after 20.001 seconds (2 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 udevd           D    0 26961   1837 0x80004006
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 Call Trace:
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? __schedule+0x355/0x750
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  schedule+0x3e/0xc0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xf/0x20
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  __mutex_lock.isra.0+0x25e/0x510
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? try_to_wake_up+0x75/0x6a0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? _raw_spin_unlock+0xd/0x20
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? __queue_work+0x154/0x430
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  sr_block_release+0x18/0x40
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  __blkdev_put+0x1b6/0x1d0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? disk_flush_events+0x4b/0x60
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  blkdev_close+0x1d/0x20
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  __fput+0xa9/0x230
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  task_work_run+0x7f/0xa0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  do_exit+0x347/0xb00
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? devkmsg_write.cold+0x24/0x46
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  do_group_exit+0x35/0x90
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  get_signal+0x13a/0x880
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? vfs_writev+0xbe/0xf0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  do_signal+0x2b/0x620
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? recalibrate_cpu_khz+0x10/0x10
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? ktime_get_ts64+0x41/0xe0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  exit_to_usermode_loop+0x65/0xb0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  do_syscall_64+0xef/0x110
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RIP: 0033:0x7f312be2dac3
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 Code: Bad RIP value.
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RSP: 002b:00007ffdbe2ab7d8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000007
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RAX: fffffffffffffdfc RBX: 00007ffdbe2ab858 RCX: 00007f312be2dac3
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RDX: 00000000000003e8 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 00007ffdbe2ab858
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RBP: 20c49ba5e353f7cf R08: 000000000000c000 R09: 00007ffdbe2ada20
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 R10: 0000000000006959 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000000003e8
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000000000aba9500 R15: 000055bc3b411180
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 cdrom_id        D    0 26969  26961 0x00000004
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 Call Trace:
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? __schedule+0x355/0x750
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  schedule+0x3e/0xc0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  blk_queue_enter+0x15e/0x270
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? wait_woken+0x70/0x70
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  blk_mq_alloc_request+0x59/0xd0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  blk_get_request+0x1e/0x60
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  sg_io+0x97/0x3b0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? blk_mq_run_hw_queue+0x43/0xe0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  scsi_cmd_ioctl+0x223/0x3c0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  cdrom_ioctl+0x37/0xddd
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0xf/0x30
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? __pm_runtime_resume+0x44/0x50
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  sr_block_ioctl+0x99/0xc0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  blkdev_ioctl+0x299/0xa10
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  block_ioctl+0x34/0x40
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  do_vfs_ioctl+0x3e6/0x640
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? preempt_count_add+0x44/0x90
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? __fd_install+0x49/0xc0
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ksys_ioctl+0x35/0x70
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  ? switch_fpu_return+0x28/0x130
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x11/0x20
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  do_syscall_64+0x43/0x110
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RIP: 0033:0x7f3146bbd2b7
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 Code: Bad RIP value.
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RSP: 002b:00007fffc77c9e08 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fffc77c9e20 RCX: 00007f3146bbd2b7
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RDX: 00007fffc77c9ea0 RSI: 0000000000002285 RDI: 0000000000000003
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 RBP: 0000565531d002a0 R08: 00007fffc77c9e20 R09: 0000000000000000
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 R10: fffffffffffffcf2 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000003
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00007fffc77c9fd0 R15: 00007fffc77caed8
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 OOM killer enabled.
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 Restarting tasks ... done.
Sat May 23 08:30:24 2020 PM: suspend exit
```

Comment: I've had lots of fun with `cdrom_id` in the past for a CDROM behind a cheap chinese USB-to-IDE bridge. Ended up completely disabling it in the udev-rules.

Comment: @dirkt Did you disable any udev rules containing `cdrom_id (--lock-media/--eject-media)` so that the device worked, or did you disable the whole device to prevent uninterruptible sleeps and rebooting?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "device". You need udev rules for your system to work. I disabled `udisks`, and anything that tried to `cdrom_id`, by changing/adding udev rules. I don't remember the details, it's been a while. It was quite painful to work through. Your case may or may not be similar to mine.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for your help - I meant did your changes to the udev rules completely disable the physical cdrom device (but e.g. stop your system from freezing), or did you solve your problem whilst still being able to use the cdrom?

Comment: The whole point was still to be able to use the CD-ROM. All this automatic detection stuff isn't really needed (except maybe for "the desktop"). Which makes it doubly annoying when it crashes.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks, that's clear to me now and very helpful!  I've done something similar, and though I'm far from sure, it might just prevent this from happening again.

Comment: My solution was to comment out the lines `ENV{DISK_EJECT_REQUEST}=="?*", RUN+="cdrom_id --eject-media $devnode", GOTO="cdrom_end"` and `IMPORT{program}="cdrom_id --lock-media $devnode"` in the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules`.  However, this is not perfect, because this file gets overwritten by updates of the udev package.  Custom rules are supposed to be in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`.  How can I create a file with rules there that **override** the default rules?